# Apache Timezone vs OS (Linux RedHat) Timezone

Tags: linux, apache, redhat

Is there a difference between the timezone setting for the OS (a RedHat Linux build in my case) and the timezone for the actual Apache server on that OS? If so, which of the two am I seeing when I run `date` on the command line, and how can I change them individually? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the system-wide time zone should be the one you're seeing when running the `date` command. Apache should not, by default, have an additional time zone configured.

Software such as PHP, if you're running it, can have additional time zone settings (for PHP, it can be defined in the `php.ini` file via the `date.timezone` option).

Comment: So it's possible that the Apache setting could be different from what you see what you run `date` on the command line? If so, I assume the Apache setting would be in one of my "conf" files?

Comment: Depends on what software you're running on the Apache. If you're running PHP, it would usually be defined in the `/etc/php.ini` file for system-wide settings, or via an Apache `SetEnv` option in a "conf" file. It could even be defined via a `.htaccess` file.

Comment: We have a timezone setting in `/etc/php.ini`, which is different from what you get when you run `date` on the command line (part of the bug I'm chasing). Assuming there's no `SetEnv` option or .htaccess setting, would Apache defer to the PHP setting over what is set on the OS?

Comment: Apache (per se) should not care overmuch, but the PHP application running on the Apache server should honor the PHP time zone settings.